# GA4: total revenue is 0 and Monetization screen not showing data

Tags: e-commerce, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to integrate ecommerce tracking to a website. The problem is the events are captured and I'm sending all the data.
This is the data I'm sending

```
{
"event": "purchase",
"currency": "EUR",
"value": 21.85,
"items": [
    {
        "item_id": "3cd937-debc-416d-955f-8ccc84a751",
        "item_name": "anuy-namer",
        "affiliation": "",
        "coupon": "",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "discount": 0,
        "index": 1,
        "item_brand": "Fontastic",
        "item_category": "THeadset / Lautsprecher",
        "item_category2": "Unterhaltungk - Körer",
        "item_category3": "",
        "item_category4": "",
        "item_category5": "",
        "item_list_id": "31baa491-4c6f-8671-c808f0cb2100",
        "item_list_name": "Fontastic BT In-Ear Headset S1 blau Bluetooth-Kopfhörer",
        "item_variant": "Mit Begleiterliche Musikfans.",
        "location_id": "",
        "price": 14.95,
        "quantity": 1
    }
],
"transaction_id": "9826314a-46af-4304-a057-dc77f4a799b0",
"affiliation": "446c6345-9193-4841-9f4a-e06e8cf7220e",
"tax": "3.4917",
"shipping": "6.9000",
"coupon": "",
"gtm.uniqueEventId": 12
```

}

tbh I'm not sure if the data is wrong but the monetization reports only show number of purchasers and not anything else. It's all zeros. in the conversion screen the total revenue is not calculated.

Comment: Maybe it could be that shipping and tax are strings and not integers. Watch the structure in the link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag#measure_purchases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the setup wasn't correct. I needed to add custom trigger to the events so It can be captured.
I also found some problem with the structure of the object, (currency,value , items) needed to be added inside ecommerce object.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have been given permission to see revenue. When someone gives you access, there are several options including one to hide revenue.

[image]

Comment: I checked the settings and these options are not checked and I'm administrator. Maybe the problem related to the data I'm sending I'm not sure.

Comment: It turned out to be some problem with the setup itself, not the code. I didn't know about this data restriction so thank you.